# Matrix filler block

Tags: java, matrix

In my class we have to make a matrix filler program but I have gotten very confused on how to do so by using the user input and I don't know how to at all. Iv'e tried to start coding but can't get past step 1.

```java
package question4;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MatrixFiller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Size of Matrix: ");
        Random ranGen = new Random();
        int matrixSize = input.nextInt();
        int a = matrixSize * matrixSize;
        input.close();
        int[][] myMatrix = new int[matrixSize][matrixSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < matrixSize; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrixSize; y++) {
                myMatrix[x][y] = ranGen.nextInt(a);
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(myMatrix[x][y]) + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

so i fixed the code and was wandering how can i add the zero inferno of the number like 1 and 2 so it comes out 01 and 02, do i need an if loop so that it only checks numbers less then 10?

Comment: Here's a start: You make a 2 dimensonal array (i.e. a matrix): ```int [][] arr = new int[x][x]```, then you start filling in the arrray as you take in the numbers from the user via a nested loop. E.g. the ```08``` on line 3 would go to ```arr[2][3]``` position of the array (following row-major format)

Comment: if its random can i just import the random for java datatype cause the user is only suppose to choose the size?

Comment: "*random elements from 1 to x2.*" What is x2? The user enters it?

Comment: Yes, java ```Math``` library has a ```Random```, which you can use to [generate random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java) between 1 and x^2.

Comment: @user1803551 I think he means x^2.

Comment: i add stuff to get you and idea if my code is on right track

Comment: Your array needs to be x by x, why do you have different values for x and y? Also, did you learn about arrays? How to define one and how to access it?

Comment: @Siddhartha Huh, makes sense.

Comment: I didn't , I missed my class discussing it and I'm having a hard time trying to understand it , which is part why I made this post looking like a fool

Comment: @Phantom1421 your nested loops are on the right track, here's some more hints. First, ```scores =  [x] [y];``` makes no sense, the ```[x][y]``` needs to belong to a matrix such as ```arr``` that I mentioned above. Second, you're designing a ```square matrix```, so your loops will both run the same number of iterations. Look up java 2D matrices.

Comment: Where is your code for reading user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your example code it seems that what you are missing is basic syntax knowledge. Let me refresh your memory on arrays at the most basic level with simple language.

Arrays are like a multi-dimensional list of variables of some type.

- You choose the type of variables when you *declare* the array.
- The amount of variables which an array can hold is a constant number (the `length` of the array) which is defined when is is *initialized*.
- An array can also have more than one dimensions. You set the number of dimensions when you *declare* the array. Think of a 1 dimensional array as a list, 2 dimensions would turn the list into a matrix. In this case, you need to *set the length of each dimension (when you initialize)*. So, if the length of the 2 dimensions is the same you get a square, otherwise you get a rectangle.

Here is some code to go along with this:

```
int[] myArray;
```

Here I *declared* a 1 dimensional array which holds `int`s.

```
myArray = new int[6];
```

Here I *initialized* my array and set the length of the dimension to 6.

```
int[] myArray2 = new int[7];
```

I can also do them on the same line.

```
long[][] myMatrix = new long[3][2];
```

Here I declared a 2 dimensional array which holds `long`s. The lengths of the dimensions are 3 and 2, so it looks like this when you imagine it:

```
_ _
_ _
_ _
```

Now we wan to *access* the array at a certain position. This is done by specifying the array name and the position in each dimension you want to access, like this:

```
myMatrix[0][1] = 63;
```

**Remember!** The position start counting from 0, so a 2 by 3 array would have the first dimension values 0 and 1; and the second dimension values 0, 1 and 2.

Now let's *iterate* over an array and put the number 6 in all of its slots:

```
int[][] exmaple = new int[3][3]; // 2 dim. array of ints with size 3 by 3.
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
         example[x][y] = 6;
    }
}
```

Not sure if you need this, but I will mention a few additional notes:

- You can initialize an array with values directly and then you don't need to specify the dimensions' lengths:

  ```
  int[][] array = new int[][] {{1 ,2}, {5, 65}}; // 2 by 2
  ```
- You can get the length of a dimension of an array by the syntax

  ```
  array.length;    
  array[0].length;
  array[1].length;
  // etc.
  ```

  These return an `int` which you can use as a bound when looping:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: i edited my code with more things, is it making more sense, and i still don't fully understand how to get an array working???

Comment: @Phantom1421 I don't see you using anything I explained.

Comment: Start by fixing your syntax errors using what I explained.

Comment: your syntax wants me to set the values before, but i need to have them userdefined?

Comment: Set the values before what? You read from the user the length of the dimensions, use that number to *initialize* the array.

Comment: Yes! Now, use the syntax for iterating and putting values into the array. Also, what are you declaring `int x` and `int myMatrix` for? Remember that `x` and `y` need to be `int`s in the loops.

Comment: well see i need to implement the random datatype which i imported but i don't know how to set the matrix for it?

Comment: The datatype of the array is `int`. What you need to do is generate a random int, but before you do that you have to fix your syntax.

Comment: i think i fixed my syntax??

Comment: when i run the code it prints these weird numbers, [[I@4e25154f

Comment: You fixed the syntax. But `int[][] myMatrix = new int[ranInt][ranInt];` makes the matrix of random size instead of using the size given by the user. And `myMatrix [x][y]= matrixSize;` puts the value of the size of the matrix in all of its cells. About the print, you need to iterate over the array and print each value, you can't print an array variable.

Comment: ok edited it but when i print i get one long line of matrix with the , Size of Matrix: 5
[[6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]

Comment: You get the same value because you generate a value and save it in `int ranInt= ranGen.nextInt(9);`. Then you put that value in all the cells with `myMatrix [x][y]= ranInt;`. Instead, you want to generate a new value for each cell. Also, why do you generate a number between 1 and 9?

Comment: so firs too i run the ranInt in an if loop or someplace, and also it part of the homework where he says the a number 0-9

Comment: `ranGen.nextInt(9);` gives you a new random int. Just put it directly into your array cell. Also, in your example there are numbers greater than 9, so I was confused. Whichever number it is, you're doing it correctly.

Comment: i think i got but how do i put staking on top of each other ?

Comment: Now that you are not using `ranInt` you can remove it. What stacking? You want to print the array like a matrix? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061912/printing-out-a-2-d-array-in-matrix-format)?

Comment: dont know why but it doesn't work???, i edited my code and it does work for some odd reason

Comment: @Phantom1421 Do a separate loop for putting the values and a separate one for printing, as shown in the example.

Comment: So I need to add an extra loop for just the printing?

Comment: @Phantom1421 You don't have to, you can print as you iterate through the first loops, I just think you'll understand better if you do them separately.

Comment: @Phantom1421 I pasted a link in the previous comments that shows you how to do it. You really need just to copy-paste from there.

Comment: [Search the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851403/save-an-integer-in-two-digit-format-in-a-variable-in-java).

Comment: i changed my code and added some things if you want to see and i have one more thing that it will be finished, and also i really and very thankful for your help @user1803551

Comment: it can't format object into a given number is what get as an error?

Comment: Your sentence makes no sense. Copy paste the answer in the link.